# Insanely high mysqld write I/O on SELECT queries

Tags: linux, mysql

I am struggling to find a reason for my mysql have this much of disk write, it just doesn't make any sense. It it doing mostly of the time `SELECT` queries, so the only reason I find to it write so much data is of **JOIN** queries that must be cached on disk. I have a medium WordPress stack with **6 thousand** posts, **15k terms** and about **80k metas**. The database dump itself is only 150mb.

The `general_log` generated by these monstruous I/O can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/Pu5YrFz9

[image: iotop output]
[image: Linode longview report]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess there are lots of disk-based temporary tables created for sorting and other stuff. Keep your eye on `created_disk_tmp_tables` MySQL variable.

Comment: Hi Janne! Thanks for the answer! Here is the output:
`Created_tmp_disk_tables = 25335 / Created_tmp_files = 2664 / Created_tmp_tables = 64171`

Comment: So about 40% of your queries lead to disk-based temporary tables. That might not be as severe thing as it sounds, but of course it could be. If possible, try giving your MySQL bigger `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` values, restart your MySQL server process and see how it goes.

Comment: I've set them up to 512M each and I am watching how it goes. It appears to have dropped to 25%, for now.

Comment: Janne! I never really answered this, it was a really bad query that was breaking everything creating tons of temp tables. I've rewritten it and now mysql is working like a charm!

Comment: Great to hear you got it working. Have an excellent week!